# Jira Issues (User Stories) integrated with GIT Issues (Developer Tasks)

Tags: github, jira

All,

- How do you associate a GitHub issue (developer task) to a Jira issue (user story).
- And how do you configure Jira to have full visibility into GitHub issue status, and commits?

As background, we currently use Jira Cloud.

Comment: Please add any relevant code so we can best assist you!

Comment: Git itself has no concept of issues. I suspect you're thinking of a particular provider like GitHub, GitLab, or Bitbucket. Please edit your question to add this information.

Answer (score 1):

JIRA integrates with [Atlassian Stash](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash). You can set up integrations to change the status of the JIRA according to things like when a pull request is opened or merged. You will also have links from the JIRA page to see the individual commits. See the **JIRA INTEGRATION** section on the link.